# Successfully bind and use Vidyo in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: video, binding, xamarin.ios

I just want to ask if there is anyone that successfully bound and used Vidyo (http://www.vidyo.com/) in a Xamarin iOS app?

Comment: Xamarin is not officially supported by Vidyo, but from what I understand, it is possible to make it work using raw frames. Also, I believe that they are working on a Xamarin sample which will make its way to developer.vidyo.com

Comment: You could write your own iOS bindings.